# List of dictionaries: how do I quickly test all members of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am manipulating a list of dictionaries, example:

```
mylist = [
    {'score':11, 'type':'dftz'},
    {'score':15, 'type':'dftz'},
    {'score': 8, 'type':'xcdt'},
    {'score': 3, 'type':'xcdt'}
]
```

I would like to:

1. get the list index of all members which have a score higher than 10
2. get a list or tuple containing all scores, as follows: [11,15,8,3]

What's the simplest and fastest way of doing so in python3? For the moment I handle it with a loop where each member is tested iteratively. Is there a more 'beautiful' way of doing it?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in Py3 that greatly differs from Py2 here, and I don't know of any other solution to get values from a list than to iterate over the list one way or another. You'd have to post your existing code. Also, if what you want is to improve existing, working code, then codereview might be a better place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Beautiful' is of course subjective, but I would use a list comprehension as follows:

```
mylist = [
    {'score':11, 'type':'dftz'},
    {'score':15, 'type':'dftz'},
    {'score': 8, 'type':'xcdt'},
    {'score': 3, 'type':'xcdt'}
]

scores = [x['score'] for x in mylist]

indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(scores) if x>10]
```

**Out:**

```
>>> scores
[11, 15, 8, 3]
>>> indexes
[0, 1]
```

Comment: This is still iterating over the lists - and this time twice ;-) But that's probably what I'd do to, unless it's a huge dataset.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers How "huge" do you mean?

Comment: @StefanPochmann "huge" is always relative - in this case relative to how often this code is executed and how critical perfs are for this part of the code. As a starting point I'd say "huge" begins at hundreds or more items... but if you want to be serious you have to profile the thing to find out how much of a problem it is for your own use case.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I did profile it with lists up to a *million* items and this double-iteration solution was consistently *faster* than kuro's deleted single-iteration solution by about factor 2: https://repl.it/repls/ElementaryRewardingWrapper

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Even after improving kuro's by using `scores_append = scores.append` and `indexes_append = indexes.append` it's still about factor 1.7 slower. I doubt you could really make it faster. Maybe if "huge" means "too large for physical RAM".

Comment: @StefanPochmann Then it looks like py3 optimized list comprehensions even more - or that I got something wrong last time I benchmarkerd both solutions (which is quite some times ago actually). Thanks for sharing btw.

Comment: thanks for your answers! Initially I was wondering if there was something equivalent to matlab's function idx=find(scores>=10). But I can live with using for loops ;-)